# Stackdriver Trace not showing traces from Zipkin by Express API correctly

Tags: express, zipkin, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-trace

In our cluster, we have set up a Zipkin collector for Stackdriver Trace ([like this](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/zipkin)) so we can trace our apps.

I am running the simple [JavaScript web example](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-js-example) that is offered. It works correctly when I configure the app to send the traces to the collector that is running in the cluster (in `recorder.js`).

However, when I want to inspect the traces in Stackdriver Trace, something seems to be going wrong:

[image]

The **HTTP Method** column is empty, and the **URI** column seems to show the HTTP method. How can I make these columns display the correct information?

Let me know if I need to add more information.

Comment: A similar discussion at [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-zipkin/issues/34) discusses span name convention to be a potential cause. However this was discussed for the [Stackdriver Zipkin Collector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-zipkin) (" a drop-in replacement for the standard Zipkin HTTP collector")

Comment: Thanks @Fady. I saw that issue already, but there was no real solution.

Comment: I suggest  posting the issue at the same GitHub thread for progression.